# Refer to a function param in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

Attempt of a function:

```
plot_eval <- function(data, metric) {
  data |> 
    ggplot(aes(x = cut, y = metric)) +
    geom_point() +
    ggtitle(metric)
}
```

Tried with diamonds data set e.g:

```
plot_eval(diamonds, price)
Error in dots_list(..., title = title, subtitle = subtitle, caption = caption, :
object 'price' not found
```

I would like the function to run in the following way, here I create the plot directly outside of a function:

```
diamonds |> 
  ggplot(aes(x = cut, y = price)) +
  geom_point() +
  ggtitle('price')
```

Produces a plot:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I6qMD.png)

How can I call my function to get the same result:

```
plot_eval(diamonds, price)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do:

```r
library(ggplot2)

plot_eval <- function(data, metric) {
  
  metric <- enquo(metric)
  
  data |> 
    ggplot(aes(x = cut, y = !!metric)) +
    geom_point() +
    ggtitle(metric)
}

plot_eval(diamonds, price)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-09-15 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thank you! That does indeed work. Now to google for enquo...

Answer (score 4):

If you want to pass columns use `curlycurly {{}}` and in the ggtitle to pass the string use `deparse(substitute(y))`. For more details see https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html

```
plot_eval <- function(data, x, y) {
  data  %>%  
    ggplot(aes(x = {{x}}, y = {{y}})) +
    geom_point() +
    ggtitle(deparse(substitute(y)))
}

plot_eval(diamonds, cut, price)
```

[image]